# Django - reverse nested url with drf-nested-routers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, drf-nested-routers, django-url-reverse

I configured my api url as

```
localhost:port/app_name/students/{student_id}/macro/{macro_id}/lto
```

using **drf-nested-routers** extension. Basically, each students has some macro categories assigned, that in turns have some Long Term Objectives (LTOs). I've tested it using *curl* and *Postman* and everything seems to work.
Now I need to write a more precise test case for my LTO model.
This is my **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.conf.urls import include
from rest_framework import routers
from app_name.views.views import UserViewSet, StudentViewSet, MacroViewSet, LTOViewSet, MacroAssignmentViewSet
from rest_framework_nested import routers as nested_routers

# application namespace
app_name = 'app_name'

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user')
router.register(r'macro', MacroViewSet, basename='macro')
router.register(r'macro-assignments', MacroAssignmentViewSet, basename='macro-assignment')

student_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
student_router.register(r'students', StudentViewSet, basename='student')
lto_router = nested_routers.NestedSimpleRouter(student_router, r'students', lookup='student')
lto_router.register(r'macro/(?P<macro_pk>.+)/lto', LTOViewSet, basename='lto')


urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^', include(router.urls)),
    re_path('^', include(student_router.urls)),
    re_path('^', include(lto_router.urls)),
]
```

**The issue is that I cannot use the **reverse()** method correctly to get the url of my LTOViewSet to test it.**

```
self.url = reverse('app_name:student-detail:lto', {getattr(self.student, 'id'), getattr(self.macro, 'id')})
```

This gives the following error

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'student-detail' is not a registered namespace inside 'app_name'
```

In other test cases, I use very similar sentences and those work fine

```
self.list_url = reverse('app_name:student-list')

reverse('app_name:student-detail', {post_response.data['id']})
```

Comment: Side Note: You don't have to create `routers.DefaultRouter` objects more than once

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Even if I don't want to have `student_router`'urls nested with those ones of `router`?

Comment: So does knowing what [URL namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) are, help you? You're trying to reference lto by namespace, which you haven't created.

Comment: @Melvyn from what I've understood, for each **namespace** corresponds a **app_name**. I have everything inside a single app, so I shouldn't use other namespaces

Comment: The error message and reverse call don't match up: `reverse('app_name:student-detail:lto'` versus `Reverse for 'student-detail-lto'`. See colon versus -. So which of the two is it?

Comment: @Melvyn the second one, sorry. I've just updated the question. That was another attempt i made to find a solution

Comment: I can't reproduce this, with a reduced version of what you have. You're also passing in a set, so even if you resolve your current issue you will get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`. But to get to the bottom: add `print(student_router.urls)` above `urlpatterns` and then see if student-detail is there.

Comment: @Melvyn you're right. **student-detail** is included in **print(student_router.urls)**. Actually I found a possible solution: `self.url = reverse('app_name:lto-list', (getattr(self.student, 'id'), getattr(self.macro, 'id')))`  As I understand, you must always define **-list** or **-detail** at the end of the url you want to reverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's the minimally reproducible example:

```
# main/viewsets.py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group


class StudentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = User


class LTOViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = Group
```

```py
# main/urls.py
from django.urls import re_path, include
from rest_framework import routers

from rest_framework_nested import routers as nested_routers
from .viewsets import StudentViewSet, LTOViewSet

# application namespace
app_name = "main"

student_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
student_router.register(r"students", StudentViewSet, basename="student")
lto_router = nested_routers.NestedSimpleRouter(
    student_router, r"students", lookup="student"
)
lto_router.register(r"macro/(?P<macro_pk>.+)/lto", LTOViewSet, basename="lto")

urlpatterns = [
    re_path("^", include(student_router.urls)),
    re_path("^", include(lto_router.urls)),
]
```

```py
reverse('main:lto-detail', args=(1,1,1))
Out[5]: '/api/students/1/macro/1/lto/1/'
```

So indeed your error was passing just the router basename not a final endpoint to reverse and because of the nesting we were thrown off by student-detail not reversing (which I still don't get).

Comment: `student-detail` does not need to get reversed manually. Once Django knows the final endpoint ('lto-detail/list' in this case), he automatically reverse the entire nested url. The only things he requires are the arguments in the url --> the primary key of student and of a macro in this case

Comment: Ah, I see now...when you updated the error message it complained about the namespace, not the url name anymore. All makes sense now!

Comment: Do you know whether I can use this approach to test nested urls?